# What happened to Hermione's wand after that it was confiscated?

Tags: harry-potter

> Hermione's wand was confiscated by Snatchers in the spring of 1998 when she, Harry, and Ron were caught after Harry accidentally broke the Taboo curse by saying Voldemort's name. Hermione subsequently used Bellatrix Lestrange's 12¾" walnut and dragon heartstring wand, which Harry grabbed during their escape from Malfoy Manor.
>
> <sub>[Harry Potter Wiki, Hermione Granger's wand, Confiscation](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Hermione_Granger%27s_wand)</sub>

What happened to Hermione's wand? Did she get it back?

Comment: If you're copying text from an external source, can you indicate as such with quote markdown in the future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not stated in the book or any other media that I know of.

She of course would not keep using Bellatrix's (she is disgusted by it and she is not the master of that wand).

The obvious answer is, in my opinion, that the Ministry raided Malfoy Manor after the war, and recovered the stolen wands.

And what if the wands were destroyed? I don't think the Death Eaters would destroy useful wands, but she was considered a mudblood so that's a possibility. In that case, Hermione would have simply bought a new wand at Ollivanders.

Luna also lost her original wand and got a new one from Ollivander. Hermione says in *Deathly Hallows* that she wishes he made another one for her.

> “I miss my wand,” Hermione said miserably. “I wish Mr. Ollivander could have made me another one too.”
>
> Mr. Ollivander had sent Luna a new wand that morning. She was out on the back lawn at that moment, testing its capabilities in the late afternoon sun. Dean, who had lost his wand to the Snatchers, was watching rather gloomily.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 26, "Gringotts"</sub>

We also don't know if Luna recovered the original or kept using the second.

Comment: Also Hermione appears to still be usig Bellatrix's wand at least up until the end of DH.

Comment: If Bellatrix lost her wand too, she might be using Hermione’s wand. So the wand ends up in Hogwarts after all , you know, after Molly dispersoned the wand. Just a possibility though

Comment: @atayenel True, but Hermione would not be the master of that wand and it would be useless, because Molly is the new owner.

Comment: @atayenel For what it's worth, in the movie Bellatrix wand is not Hermione's (I just rewatched Molly and Bella's battle). But if we neglet this little detail, your theory is good! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that she didn't get it back, or if she did, for some reason (it got broken or lost, perhaps) she stopped using it by the time the events of Cursed Child take place.

Her [wand in the play](https://cursedchildstore.co.uk/products/hermione-granger-official-replica-wand) is significantly different, both in design and wood type.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think that Cursed Child doesn't count. Harry's wand is different, too.

Comment: @shot22 - You are, of course, welcome to consider that it doesn't count. JKR considers that it counts though...

Comment: So Harry, after he was lucky enough to fix his broken wand, threw it away and bought another one? It makes sense. Is there any reference of Hermione's new wand in the Cursed Child screenplay? I don't think so. It's not canon.

Comment: @shot22 Of course, in the Film he *doesn't* repair his wand...